# iphone web develop mode (inspect element) on windows safari

Tags: iphone, safari, element, inspect

I found two ways how i can easier develop web app for iPhone.

http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari/

But I can't do it on Windows, because for windows is only Safari 5. Have you any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Get a Mac, there is no support for this on Windows.

Comment: I haven't gotten it to work, but this theoretically would help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35714766/470749

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on doing iOS development!  As pointed out in the comments, your best bet is to be running Mac OS when developing on iOS, whether you're developing a native or web application.  Just as if you were to develop a Windows application where you'd need to be running Microsoft Windows, you'll need Mac OS to do iOS development.

Good luck!

Comment: You actually don't need a Windows machine to write Windows apps (or Linux for Linux apps), particularly for web-based ones. Apple just goes to great lengths to require a Mac for iOS development and testing.

However, tools and services like BrowserStack can help a lot here.

Answer (score -6):

That's no big deal if you want to develop a web app because all you got to know is some XHTML and I would recommend that you get Dreamweaver for a better experience :)