# How to debug webite for ios.iphone with windows PC

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, google-chrome, debugging

My client website working ok on all devices but having problem with Iphone.

I tried to debug website for iPhone with google chrome inspect element mobile tool, but it not help because chrome mobile tool not appears the issue which my client talking about

Can anyone help me how can I debug website for iPhone with window PC
Thanks for help

Comment: Best answer for 2018 from a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38786618/6221448

Answer (score 3):

I've been using WebIDE. It's a Firefox add-on that enables you to connect the Firefox Developer Tools to a number of other browsers, including Firefox for Android, Chrome on Android, and Safari on iOS. 
You'll need Firefox 37+ or the developer edition. You can find instructions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Valence) (MDN)
and [here](http://washamdev.com/2016/02/debug-a-website-in-ios-safari-on-windows/) (More to the point)

**Note:**
It's not working (at least for me) with the latests version of iOS (it did work with iOS 8). It does connect, but it doesn't see the pages you are navigating in your device.

Comment: Yeah I can confirm WebIDE is not finding my iPhone (iOS 10).

Comment: Same here. And https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Valence says it has only been tested on iOS 6, 7, and 8.

Answer (score -3):

You can use Web Inspector Tool in Safari.

1. Open website in Safari browser in your iPhone.
2. Now connect your iPhone with Mac.
3. Open Safari Browser on Mac/Windows.
4. In Menu Bar of Safari select Develop -> Your iPhone Device name -> Web Page to debug. This will open Debug inspector and show all your webpages .you can debug it easily.
   As shown in fig:
   [image]

If Develop menu is not available you can enable it from Preferences -> Advance and  check Show Develop menu.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but read question again I want to debug with window pc, i don't have mac & iphone

Comment: You need at least one iPhone device to test on iPhone platform.

Comment: Its optional either u can use Mac or Window.

Comment: as you say Now connect your iPhone with pc, i don't have iphone

Comment: Sorry for that, but you cannot get 100% iOS device environment on any browser or simulator. U need to test on device to find exact issue.

Comment: These instructions haven't worked for me. I'm using Safari 5.1.7 on Windows 10 and an iPhone 6 (iOS 9.3.4) with lightning cable. In my Windows Safari "Develop" menu, I don't see any device listed. (And yes, my phone successfully connects to iTunes). I wonder if Apple changed something about their software. If anyone has any other suggestions, I'd appreciate them!

Comment: http://adaptivejs.mobify.com/v2.0/docs/debug-on-ios-devices-and-the-ios-simulator/ has cool animations that agree with your steps though. I wish I could figure out why my iPhone doesn't appear in the Windows Safari Develop menu.